# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable- Python

Tags: python-2.7

I write this code

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    """
    Computes the value of a polynomial function at given value x. Returns that
    value as a float.

    Example:
    >>> poly = [0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 9.3, 7.0]    # f(x) = 5x^2 + 9.3x^3 + 7x^4 
    >>> x = -13
    >>> print evaluate_poly(poly, x)  # f(-13) = 5(-13)^2 + 9.3(-13)^3 + 7(-13)^4 
    180339.9

    poly: list of numbers, length > 0
    x: number
    returns: float
    """
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE ...
    answer = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(poly)):
        answer +=poly[i]*(x**i)
    return float(answer)
```

and consistently get the response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    evaluate_poly( [0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 9.3, 7.0], -13)
  File "/Users/katharinaross/Downloads/ps2/ps2_bisection.py", line 28, in evaluate_poly
    answer +=poly[i]*(x**i)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

All of the """ are notes from my professor on examples of how the code should run. what does this mean?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message with the code that you have in your question. Are you *sure* you have `poly[i]` and not `poly(i)`?

Comment: Do you have `float = ...` somewhere in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

That error message is the *exact* one I get when I use the line:

```
answer += poly(i)*(x**i)
```

(using parentheses rather than square brackets). When I use square brackets, I get the right answer, as specified in the comments:

```
$ cat qq.py
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    """
    Computes the value of a polynomial function at given value x. Returns that
    value as a float.

    Example:
    >>> poly = [0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 9.3, 7.0]    # f(x) = 5x^2 + 9.3x^3 + 7x^4
    >>> x = -13
    >>> print evaluate_poly(poly, x)  # f(-13) = 5(-13)^2 + 9.3(-13)^3 + 7(-13)^4
    180339.9

    poly: list of numbers, length > 0
    x: number
    returns: float
    """
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE ...
    answer = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(poly)):
        answer +=poly[i]*(x**i)
    return float(answer)

print evaluate_poly ([0.0,0.0,5.0,9.3,7],-13)

$ python qq.py
180339.9
```

Hence either you've gone out of your way to doctor the code and output (unlikely) or you have a problem with the way your Python interpreter is handling the indexing operator.

Since that works fine in other environments, it's unlikely to be that code itself, so you'll need to search for some other cause.

As a first step, you should create a file containing absolutely nothing except the contents of my `qq.py` file above and run it to see if it exhibits a similar problem.

Secondly, I would check that the file your stack trace is being raised in (`/Users/katharinaross/Downloads/ps2/ps2_bisection.py`) is actually the one you *think* it is.

Also show us the *entire* file since there may be stuff at the top affecting your given code.

I mention all that since that exception is not on the 28th line in your sample code (as per the stack trace), it's actually around line 19, so there's probably something above it which you haven't shown us.